# Regular Expression to find uncommented apache config tags?

Tags: php, regex

First see this commented tag that is for apache virtualHost config file:

```
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>
```

How can find uncommented tags and get content between theme?

Comment: Rather than regex, you'd probably be better off just finding a parser for Apache config files. [This might work](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.configuration.config.avail-container.apache.php).

Comment: @Wiseguy Realy tnx bor... That isnt what I want... but it is very good

Answer (score 2):

use this regex `^\s*[^#\s].+?$` with regex option `multyline` you catch matchCollection uncommented rows

Answer (score 2):

```
$subject = '##<VirtualHost *:80>
##ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.localhost"
##ServerName dummy-host2.localhost
##ServerAlias www.dummy-host2.localhost
##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
##</VirtualHost>';

$pattern = '=[#]{1,}<VirtualHost.[^>]*>(.*?)</VirtualHost>=is';
$result = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

echo '<pre>'.print_r($matches, true).'</pre>';
```

In $matches[1] you will find what you are looking for